# Is HTML5 file API really going to change the file uploading experience for user?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, html

I am using the HTML5 File API to upload the file to server.

It offers following amazing things,

1. Upload object which support the [*progress*](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/) event which make it possible to show nice progress UI to end user.
2. [XHR.send(File) and XHR.send(FormData)](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) can carry big files(decent sized off course ) across the wire with no need to load entirely in memory.
3. [input type="file" with multiple](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)
   option.
4. Drag Drop from desktop in Firefox and Chrome.

All looks promising and good however still considering its our good old HTTP which is there and unpredictable network. I would like to know if HTML5 is still really going to change file upload experience beyond UI progress and all. Or it will be same HTTP 2GB max request size (ASP.NET) and bandwidth restrictions. Will it allow big file sizes.

Comment: Me thinks it's going to be the same as before but I do like the progress notifications!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 (or any other mark-up language) won't and can't change any server-side rules or bypass any bandwidth restrictions.